# Stability of non-autonomous stochastic differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I'm looking for a good reference or insight to under what conditions can I prove stability (or instability) for the following general n-dimensional non-autonomous stochastic differential equation:

$dX = A(t)X(t)dt+\sigma dW$

EDIT: What I've read on stochastic stability assumes that the stochastic term =0 when x=0. My stochastic term is constant and independent of x so I'm not sure if I can apply those results. I'm looking for what I can say under certain conditions, i.e. if the eigenvalues of A(t) are always <0 then the expectation of x is within a ball of radius $\sigma^2$ or something of that flavor.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "stability"?

Comment: I mean stochastic stability or stochastic asymptotic stability